# To find another piece of a zip partitioned compressed file

Tags: zip, compression

The following files exist:

```
compress.zip
compress.z01
compress.z02
compress.z03
compress.z04
compress.z05 (fake)
```

An error occurs in the above case.
Is there a way to get information about other partitioned compressed file fragments by reading compressed.zip?

For example, information about z01, z02, z03, and z04

Comment: Is there some code involved or why did you tag this question with “Java”?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a mistake.

Comment: What kind of information you search for? Or do you want to recover the files from compressed archive?

Comment: I want to read the compress.zip file and get the file name of another split compression file.
ex) z01, z02, z03, z04

Comment: I was able to analyze the file header to determine the compression time, but some files are missing information.